# Remember LazyColumn scrolling position for collecting data via Paging3 library

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-paging-3

Is it even possible to remember LazyColumn scrolling position in such a case?

```
@Composable
fun ScreenComposable(state: State<ScreenUiState>) {
    val stateValue = state.value
    val lazyItems: LazyPagingItems<Item> = stateValue.pagingItems.collectAsLazyPagingItems()

    LazyColumn {
        lazyItems.apply {
            when (loadState.refresh) {
                is LoadState.NotLoading -> {
                    for (position in 0 until lazyItems.itemCount) {
                        item {
                            ScreenItemComposable()
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

where

```
data class ScreenUiState(
    // inside ViewModel there's pagingItems = getPagedData()
    val pagingItems: Flow<PagingData<Item>> = flow { PagingData.empty<Item>() },
)
```

```
override fun getPagedData(): Flow<PagingData<Item>> {
        return Pager(
                PagingConfig(
                        (...)
                ),
        ) {
            ScreenPagingSource()
        }.flow
}
```

It's standard Paging3 + Compose implementation, but even if, I haven't found working solution for keeping scroll state. I successfully used `verticalScroll(verticalScrollState)`, where `verticalScrollState` is kept in `ScreenUiState` for `Column` composable (without Paging3), but it doesn't work in aforementioned case.

I find it quite complex (and interesting) case, because one have to keep what was Paged already. Otherwise all paging would have to happen once again which is not UX-friendly solution. Maybe Paging should be kept in a `Room` local database? Any ideas?